# JavaScript ES5, difference between two ways to make an object that can be instance'd

Tags: javascript, instance, ecmascript-5

What is the difference between these two methods of declaring an object, from which you can make an instance?  Are there pros and cons to each?

```
//Method 1:
var myThing1 = function(){
  this.a= 2,
  this.m = function() {
    return this.a + 1;
  }
}   
var myThing1Instance = new myThing1();

//Method 2:
var myThing2 = {
  a: 2,
  m: function() {
    return this.a + 1;
  }
};
var myThing2Instance = Object.create(myThing2)
```

Comment: If you feel the duplicates aren't appropriate, please edit your question and explain why you think so. I will then gladly re-open your question

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm not asking about prototype vs this.  I'm asking about using a function and 'new' vs using an object literal and Object.create. What is the difference?

Comment: Keep in mind that Object.create assigns a prototype to an object so what I'm seeing is explained in those other posts

Comment: Is there any difference between Thing1Instance, and Thing2Instance?

Comment: Yes. I'm not entirely sure I understand your question; you can inspect them in your console to see the differences.